# Azure - Set WebSocket On from ARM json template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to turn WebSockets On for an Azure WebApp from an Azure ARM json template that deploys my whole infrastructure.

Here is an extract with regards to the Azure Web App. It doesn't work, i.e the WebSockets are still Off. I unsuccessfully tried different spelling: `webSocketsEnabled` or `WebSockets`.

```
"resources":[
{
  "name": "[variables('MyApp')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "Brazil South",
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('MyAppPlanBrazil'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('MyAppPlanBrazil')))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "MyAppAppBrazil"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('MyAppPlanBrazil')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('MyAppPlanBrazil'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "AlwaysOn": true,
      "webSocketsEnabled": true,
      "connectionStrings": [
        {
        ...
        },
        {
        ...
        },
      ]
    }
  }
 ]
```

UPDATE

As suggested in answer below I updated the `apiVersion` to `"2016-08-01"` but this still doesn't work.
Also note that while my [schema](https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json) is the one described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas), `apiVersion` is squiggled in VS and it says the authorized value is `"2015-08-01"` only.

UPDATE2

I tried the solutions below. They work for their authors but not for me. I guess the problem is elsewhere. My infrastructure is already deployed and I try to update it with `webSocketsEnabled`. Whereas in the solution below I imagine the authors directly create the web app with `webSocketsEnabled`.

Also, I coupled `webSocketsEnabled` with `alwaysOn` whereas the pricing tier of my webapp doesn't allow "AlwaysOn" (as it says in the portal I need to upgrade to use that feature) so I'll try without `alwaysOn`.

UPDATE3

At the end, the above template worked when I removed `AlwaysOn`.
Thank you to those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the above solution should work.

My initial snippet worked as well ... as soon as I removed `alwaysOn`.

Indeed, I was using a free tiers App Service Plan for which `alwaysOn` is not available. While there was no errors or anything else indicating something wrong, I could not set `webSocketEnabled` and `alwaysOn` at the same time in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Set your api version to this: "2016-08-01"

Use

"webSocketsEnabled": true

This is from the Microsoft.Web/sites template reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites

The api version you are using (2015-08-01) from:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json

Doesn't have web sockets in it, but the later one:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2016-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json

Does have webSocketsEnabled.

Comment: `"apiVersion": "2016-08-01"` didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try to use the following code. It works correctly on my side.

**Updated:** add whole test arm template and you could have a try to use the following code with your **service plan name** and **resource group name**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serverFarmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "YourPlan"
    },
    "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ResourceGroupName"
    }},
  "variables": {
    "ARMtemplateTestName": "[concat('ARMtemplateTest', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('ARMtemplateTestName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "southcentralus",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId(parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('serverFarmName')))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "ARMtemplateTest"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('ARMtemplateTestName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('serverFarmName'))]"

      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "web",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('ARMtemplateTestName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "enableWebSocket"
          },
          "properties": {
            "webSocketsEnabled": true,
            "alwaysOn": true
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('ARMtemplateTestName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "ConnString1": {
              "value": "My custom connection string",
              "type": "custom"
            },
            "ConnString2": {
              "value": "My SQL connection string",
              "type": "SQLAzure"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('ARMtemplateTestName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Appsetting"
          },
          "properties": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: It didn't work. Note that I already have a `resources` array with some `appSettings` where I've put some key value pairs. Maybe I should put `webSocketsEnabled` in there.

Comment: It works for me.  And I will update the answer with full code including appsetings and connection string .